# How can I ensure child threads in JUnit 5 unit tests have access to values set using @SystemStub?

Tags: unit-testing, junit5, environment

For child thread System.getenv() is not being set

Using JUNIT 5

```
@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class, SystemStubsExtension.class})
public class AbcTest {
   @SystemStub
   public EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables("ABC","abc");
  @SystemStub
   public SystemProperties systemProperties;
   @Test
    void test(){
       systemProperties.set("ABC","abc");
       Properties properties = System.getProperties();
       System.setProperty("ABCD","abc");
       System.out.println(properties);
       A.print();
       Assertions.assertEquals("abc",System.getenv("ABC"));
       print();
       Assertions.assertEquals("abc",System.getenv("ABC"));
        System.out.println("##");
        Runnable abcd = new ABCD();
        Thread thread = new Thread(abcd);
        thread.start();
    }
     void print(){
         System.out.println(System.getenv("ABC"));
     }
}
```

I want to child thread to also return the same System.getenv() value which is being set using @SystemStub